# Failed to read x.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format

Tags: python, pyautogui

My script searches for images, currently, those images are in the local folder and I'm using `directory = os.listdir()` to in conjunction with a for loop to add my images to an array.

I want to move these images to their own folder, so I've tried: `directory = os.listdir(r"C:\myFolder")`

And I'm getting the error: `Failed to read x.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format`.

The error is coming up against `Found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image)`

I've checked with `print(directory)` that the array is loading correctly and stepped through with the debugger one at a time to check it's being loaded correctly, I assume this means it's a permission issue?

```
image_list = []
# Get list of all files in current directory
directory = os.listdir(r"C:\myFolder")
# Find files that end with .png or .jpg and add to image_list
for file in directory:
    if file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.PNG'):
        image_list.append(file)

print(directory)

while True:
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('y.jpg') != None:      
            for image in image_list:
                  Found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
```

Comment: Or the fact that the image is invalid. Are you able to edit your image? If so, then it's not a permission error. Be sure that your program is looking in the right directory for the image, because looking in the wrong directory could also cause this error. The error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: It's the correct directory, and the images are indeed loading correctly as I explained twice in the post. This is part of a much longer script I'm trying to tidy up, I know it works correctly when I use `os.listdir()`

Comment: Could you please provide the full error message in the question?

Comment: `Exception has occurred: OSError
Failed to read CrazyJoe.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
  File "C:\Users\x\OneDrive\froggy-pirate-master\avoidShips\avoidShips3.py", line 49, in <module>
    Found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image, region=(750, 25, 1200-750, 125-25), confidence=0.94, grayscale=True)`

Comment: This error message doesn't match up with the code in your question. Does the simplified code in your question give you this error message, or is this the error message from the larger version of your code? Please provide the error message that _the code you posted_ gives.

Comment: I've redacted the personal details and irrelevant additional variables for the simplified version that is all. Both give the same error message.

Comment: The simplified: `Exception has occurred: OSError
Failed to read x.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format
  File "C:\myFolder\avoidShips3.py", line 49, in <module>
    Found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image)`